# Prevent .htaccess rules to the child folder

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my folder structure

```
www.mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com/app
www.mywebsite.com/app/firstproject
www.mywebsite.com/app/secondtproject
```

In the root directory i installed wordpress. It allows me to access the `www.mywebsite.com/app` but when i try to access the `www.mywebsite.com/app` it is always showing `page not found` i can guess that it is because of the `.htaccess` at the root folder.

Here is the `.htaccess` root folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I tried to override the `.htaccess` to the sub folders by having the below code in the `.htaccess` of the app folder but it shows the same page not found error.

```
RewriteRule ^app/ - [L]
```

How can i access the `www.mywebsite.com/app/firstproject` without that error ?

Answer (score 0):

Write all rules in the root htaccess file.
add
        RewriteRule ^app/firstproject$ - [L]
to prevent rewrite in this path.
For further rewrite within /firstproject, you need conditions and rules similar to web root

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^app/firstproject$ - [L] #add longer path first
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] #no need to escape \.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `app/.htaccess`
2. Have this code in root .htaccess:

**root .htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(index\.php$|app/) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: It still have the page not found exception after putting the above .htaccess in my root, i removed the .htaccess off `app` as you suggested.

Comment: i also removed the `.htaccess` from the `app/firstproject` is that the reason ??

Comment: Yes definitely, there should not be any .htaccess other than one in root

Comment: Though i removed other `.htaccess` it still shows the page not found error

Comment: To test whether root .htaccess is the issue just rename root .htaccess to something else and then test `/app/`

Comment: when i remove the .htaccess i can able to see the /app/ but when i try to access the app/firstproject/ i am getting 500 internal server

Comment: If you are getting 500 even without root htaccess that means there is some other issue, some other rule or code.

Comment: I am using wordpress , i guess without .htaccess wordpress willl show 500 error.. and if i put again the .htaccess it is working good..

Comment: No 500 is indication of some misconfiguration. Check your apache error log file for the exact cause of 500. You have some issue outside this htaccess

Comment: In my error_log file i don't find any entries related

Comment: I am having the /app as folder, should i make it as a subdomain ?

Comment: For every 500 error there is always something in Apache `error.log`. You just need to find its proper location in your system.

Comment: thanks, i found the error_log somewhere in cpanel.. this is the error .. [Sat Apr 04 22:50:33 2015] [error] [client 117.216.102.178] File does not exist: /home/sysaxiom/public_html/500.shtml
[Sat Apr 04 22:50:33 2015] [error] [client 117.216.102.178] SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/sysaxiom/public_html/app/GoogleMapsApi/index.php" is writeable by group
[Sat Apr 04 22:35:59 2015] [error] [client 117.216.102.178] File does not exist: /home/sysaxiom/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://sysaxiom.com/app/

Comment: None of these are indicators of 500 error. `500.shtml` is a result of previous 500 error.

Comment: This is one is when i got the page not found after using the htaccess provided,, [Sun Apr 05 12:41:06 2015] [error] [client 117.197.204.93] SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/sysaxiom/public_html/app/GoogleMapsApi/index.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://sysaxiom.com/app/

Comment: That is due to your `chmod` setting, change it to `chmod 644 `/home/sysaxiom/public_html/app/GoogleMapsApi/index.php`

Comment: after changing to 644 for the app folder, i got this one [Sun Apr 05 12:46:21 2015] [crit] [client 117.197.204.93] (13)Permission denied: /home/sysaxiom/public_html/app/GoogleMapsApi/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74502/discussion-between-vamsi-and-anubhava).

Comment: You got some serious issues with your local config/settings. I can't really fix everything remotely. If you can trust me, you can provide a temporary access to me and email me your server address with username/password and I will look into it.